# How to subnet in virtual SMB networks

Tags: hyper-v, subnet, small-business, vswitch

I'm setting up a Server 2012 R2 with Hyper-V role in a typically SMB environment (virtualized DC and Exchange on one single Host). Before, in the SBS times, there usually was one physical server, a handful of PCs and one subnet. Now, with virtualized systems, it seems to be useful to have more than one subnet, [see here](https://serverfault.com/questions/733140/should-hosts-and-guests-be-separated).

Please advice whether this environment would be a feasible one:

a) Put Users and DC/file/print server (VM1) on one subnet.

b) Give Exchange (VM2), because it has an open port 443 for incoming mail and activesync, an own subnet and allow traffic to/from local users to mail server only as needed via firewall rules.

c) Give host it's own subnet, determine one of the users PCs as admin PC and create rules and routes to grant access to the host subnet only for this PC.

Would that be ok?

Additional question:

The server is a Two-NIC-Proliant (ML150 Gen9). I plan to team these NICs and have one vSwitch. So all the traffic, i.e. the three subnets, would coexist on the one and only vSwitch and would be balanced through the teamed NICs.

Is that reasonable?

Thanks in advance,
Stefano

Comment: What would be the point/purpose/end goal of all of this subnetting? Subnetting just for the sake of it? No.

Comment: May be that we sometimes do things just because we can do them. :-) But the setting I outlined would not be that complicated and quite clean, wouldn't it? You could have firewall roules for ip addresses within one subnet, but segregating different subnets corresponds more to the habits, at least mine.

Comment: `May be that we sometimes do things just because we can do them` - That's never a reason to do something. If you don't have clearly defined needs and goals for this particular design then you're doing nothing but adding unnecessary complexity to your environment. I can't see any good reason to do what you're proposing.

Answer (score 0):

This really all depends on how you want to do it. Subnetting is commonly used for specific purposes: departments/sensitive data, wireless access, guest network, etc.

If all your users are on the same subnet, that is the common way to go.

As far as server usage, that is also up to you. I have seen environments where the DC and EX are two different things and in some, they're not. It just all depends on how you want to utilize the VM resources.